# Getting nosuchElement Exception for a web element even though I tried all possible solutions

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, test-automation-framework

I am using Selenium with Cucumber to automate one web application, But I am stuck at one element which is not working out with the XPaths and link text

I also applied the implicit and Explicit wait, 
hover mouse functionality using actions driver also 
there are no iframes involved either

But nothing seems to work out.
Can someone help me with this??

This is the web element I need to click and the HTML

I tried following XPaths: Upon validating on console them point to the web element but on when I using it in the script it throws the exception.

```
 //a[contains(text(),'Logout')

//div[@class='pull-right']/a

//*[@class='logout_class curPnt']
```

Also attaching my code snippet [image]

[image]

Comment: I guess there is iframe, can you confirm that ?

Comment: There is no iframe.. The current error that i am getting is : **unknown error: Element <a _ngcontent-c14="" class="logout_class curPnt">...</a> is not clickable at point (1399, 28). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-c1="" id="spinner">...</div>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code :

First you need to wait untill that spinner goes away :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("spinner")));
```

And then perform the click;

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".logout_class.curPnt"))).click();
```