# I absolutely cannot get this xpath to work... selecting a radio button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I have been trying for days to select this button... I've tried xpaths by ID type, input type, child of, etc. What am I missing here, why is VS unable to locate the "element" ? I can use the same command to ID and click a radio button on something such as FB or another site... (Bear with me, I'm newish to automation and making an attempt at self-teaching)

> Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//input[@id='q1_1']"}
>     (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)

```
  //radio button, if I can actually get this to work....
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@id='q1_1']")).Click();
```

[image]

Comment: What have you found elsewhere? For example this site is full of such problems, have you used the search button on the top of the page? What solutions have you tried and what results did you get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting nosuchElement Exception for a web element even though I tried all possible solutions](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/35729/getting-nosuchelement-exception-for-a-web-element-even-though-i-tried-all-possib)

Answer (score 1):

The xpath that you currently have will look for  element with tag input and id q1_1 from the current node.

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@id='q1_1']")).Click()`

So , if you have executed some scripts and the current focus is on any tag after the input tag , then

```
".//input[@id='q1_1']"
```

will not return any element .

So instead of

```
".//input[@id='q1_1']"
```

Use:

```
"//input[@id='q1_1']"  // removed the dot at the starting
```

The above locator will look for input tag with the specified Id , starting from the root , unlike your case where it searched only from the current node.

Comment: I felt like I already attempted this way (Had to reboot so lost all my undos) But I tried again with the update. Same result "Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='q1_1']"}"

Comment: @user43500 add explicit wait and check whether the element is in iframe

Comment: removing the dot(.) should work.
If not try to implement WebDriverWait.

Comment: Could you share the webpage URL?

Answer (score 0):

**Please go through a Select class, it should work**

```
 // Select By Class
  Select Radiobutton = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("q1_1")));
  Radiobutton.selectByValue("1");
  Radiobutton.selectByIndex(1);
  Thread.sleep(3000);
```

**Please go through type attribute, it also works**

`(By.cssSelector("input[type='radio']")).click();

Comment: No luck still, whatever method I try, the radio button does not get selected and I get the return "Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: " followed by the whatever action was used to attempt to locate the button.